# Is it possible to modify a Typescript type alias dynamically?

Tags: angular, typescript, type-narrowing

I am working on an Angular library that will serve as an API client. The issue I'm running into is that some of the consuming applications are using an HttpInterceptor to automatically convert date strings into Javascript Date objects while others just use the string value passed in the response.

I currently have these properties typed as `string | Date` but I would really like a way to have the union type narrowed to either `string` or `Date` based on which application is consuming the library.

I first tried declaring a type alias `type DateType = string | Date` and hoped I could override it using a `declare global` block in the consuming application but that didn't work.

I also considered defining an interface `interface DateType extends String` and then overriding that in the consuming application but I abandoned that route as I don't want to have the consuming applications have to manage the conversion between the String object and primitive.

Comment: What do you think about [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mq9odm) using *declaration merging*?  Inside the consuming app you merge into `DateTypeConfig` with a `type` property assignable to `Date` or `string`, and then all references to `DateType` will narrow automatically, as shown [here for `Date`](https://tsplay.dev/w25gjW) and [here for `string`](https://tsplay.dev/NBJdnN).  If that fully addresses your issue I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! I didn't realize you could create a type from an interface property like that.

Comment: Okay I’ll write up an answer when I get the chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't support arbitrary modifications to existing types.  In particular you can't modify [type aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases).  But TypeScript does support certain type modifications through [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html), which you can use (or abuse) to get the behavior you're looking for.

---

Essentially you can "re-open" an [interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces) declaration and *add* properties to it.  If the library's types are defined like this:

```
interface DateTypeConfig {
    [x: string]: string | Date
}
type DateType = DateTypeConfig["type"]

declare function acceptDate(date: DateType): void;
declare function produceDate(): DateType;
declare function modifyDate(date: DateType): DateType;
```

Then `DateType` is an [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into the `type` property of the `DateTypeConfig` interface.  Now the `DateTypeConfig` interface doesn't currently have a specific `type` property, but it does have a `string` [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) of type `string | Date`, so to start with, `DateType` is `string | Date`.

So by default, a consuming app would see this union.

```
const d = produceDate();
// const d: string | Date
const m = modifyDate(d);
// const m: string | Date
acceptDate(m);
```

---

But the consuming app *could* re-open the `DateTypeConfig` interface and add an explicit `type` property whose type is some subtype of `string | Date`.  (If this is in a module or your library is in a module you might need to use [`global` augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation) or [`module` augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) to get the right namespace.)

For example:

```
interface DateTypeConfig {
    type: Date;
}
```

And then automatically, the `DateType` type alias becomes `Date` instead of `string | Date`:

```
const d = produceDate();
// const d: Date
const m = modifyDate(d);
// const m: Date
acceptDate(m);
```

Or instead the app could do this:

```
interface DateTypeConfig {
    type: string;
}
```

and then `DateType` would be `string`:

```
const d = produceDate();
// const d: string
const m = modifyDate(d);
// const m: string
acceptDate(m);
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJ0gFQJ4AcIDCA9iDMAObIDeAUMvcgNoAeAXMgM5hSjkC67LjxCUAPmgwQaAXxpg8KdFgXIAvBOX5ipCowBE8-Hr40aAEwgIANnCgoYAVxAIwwEskRJcYJRAAUZpLsvjj4AJTsAG5EwGYA3OaWNnbIjs6u7rhQRGYOSL5+ERoQoRAJFta29k4ubiDIALY5wDDYBYGQwZKlRSEKCaYA9ION0OQoYAAWwBzIoByxE5MoCCQcDg28Hri4yH4NcNgARiigHsgVySjkVkRHcFbIRFDIAO6TkpHQYTSgkLCIRTdBTaMiUWgMZDDZCGCBdSBxKEjGpEBoNCDgGHTWZgIgwhxQep9fBzcB43x0BjQ2GCbi8RHQ57IFFojFgLEzGF4sAEonAkl-PFCXgyUyrEBcC5qZBZHJ5CAFMIJaHiyVmWnCMTFGiq9kNaVNMwtNqSAJKmgqtZ6jVbcQUzwQbwFBpKoA)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just type your function with a generic parameter like this?

```
declare function callApi<T extends Date | string>(): T;

const date =  callApi<Date>();
const str = callApi<string>();
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXzCgggEEAHLAHgBV4QAPDEVYAZ3gBEon4AfeVhhhZUAcwB8ACgCUALnjUA3AChlYPIPjBuCALzwCRUhUpcmU6SvWpNgmPH2Fi5KnZESZioA)

Comment: That certainly works but I was hoping to avoid generics so that the consumer wouldn't have to specify the date type all over the place. Plus there are already some instances of nested generics (Observable<HttpResponse<Model<ModelProperty>>>) so I didn't really want to add to that if I didn't have to.